# how to copy directory (folder) to usb storage

Tags: android, android-file, android-fileprovider

i am trying to copy whole directory to usb storage :

```
  File Sdfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myfolder");

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);

                intent.setType("*/*");
                 intent.setType(DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR);//For API 19+
                 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, Sdfile.getName());
                intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 47);


  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        if (requestCode == 47) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myfolder");
             copyFile(file, data.getData());

        }
```

Below code is for copy the whole folder to usb storage.

```
  private void copyFile(File src, Uri destUri) {
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

        try {
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(src));
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(getContentResolver().openOutputStream(destUri));
            byte[] buf = new byte[5024];
            bis.read(buf);
            do {
                bos.write(buf);
            } while (bis.read(buf) != -1);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (bis != null) bis.close();
                if (bos != null) bos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

when i am trying to copy the whole folder then it gives error.

Even i direct copy the whole folder to usb storage .

How can i copy whole directory ?

Comment: You have to get extractly usb folder path where you want to copy to

Comment: But how can i get that folder path of usb?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your app does not have the correct permissions. For Android versions below KitKat, you need to declare the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

`<user-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: i have given all the permission  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"></uses-permission>

Comment: I'm confused with your `src` and `dest`

```
   String filePath = src + "/" + destUri;
   File f = new File(filePath);
   bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
   bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destUri));
```

Shouldn't `bis` point to `src`? and `bos` point to `filePath`? `destUri` seems misleading when it's not the direct destination path.

And from above code, you are copying a file from USB storage to it's child folder?